# GitGraph JS not loading from CDN

Tags: javascript, cdn

I'm trying to get [GitGraph](http://gitgraphjs.com/) working and producing a GitFlow-like graph for a document I'm putting together.

Here's my HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>GitFlow</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gitgraph.js/1.11.4/gitgraph.min.css"></script>
    <script>
      var gitgraph = new GitGraph({
        template: "blackarrow",
        reverseArrow: false,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        mode: "compact"
      });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gitgraph.js/1.11.4/gitgraph.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="gitGraph"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I open this in a browser I just get an empty/blank page. In Chrome Dev console I see the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: GitGraph is not defined
at gitgraph.html:6
```

So for some reason its not pulling in GitGraph from the CDN. Can anybody spot where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working with this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>GitFlow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gitgraph.js/1.11.4/gitgraph.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="gitGraph"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gitgraph.js/1.11.4/gitgraph.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var gitgraph = new GitGraph({
        template: "blackarrow",
        reverseArrow: false,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        mode: "compact"
      });

      gitgraph.branch().commit().commit();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gitgraph.js/1.11.4/gitgraph.min.css"></script>
```

is loading the css file. You can validate it from the file extension.

It need to be

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gitgraph.js/1.11.4/gitgraph.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @brk (+1), with your suggestion I still get an empty/blank page and now the console error is "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined`"...any ideas? Maybe a bug in GitGraph itself?!